# How do I make variables available across different javascript files when the variables are declared using async/await?

Tags: javascript, async-await

```
<html>
  <!-- ... (other page content) ... -->
  <script src="common.js"></script>
  <script src="homepage.js"></script>
</html>
```

On every page on my website, I have one common.js file for stuff that is always needed on every single page. And then I have one js file specifically for that page.

My problem is that variables declared in the common.js file needs to be accessed in the second js file as well, but I am running into some issues because the script is not waiting for the data variable to be declared, and it is not allowed to use await in the top level of the script.

```
// common.js
let data;
async function get_data() {
  data = await fetch('/get-data').then(res => res.json())
  console.log(data) // works!!!
}
get_data();
console.log(data) // does not work!!!
```

```
// homepage.js
console.log(data) // does not work!!!
```

So what I am asking is how can I make the two `console.log(data)` calls that aren't working, work!

Comment: `window.data = await fetch('/get-data').then(res => res.json())`

Answer (score 1):

Create a global Promise that resolves to `data`, and then call `.then` on that Promise whenever you need to consume it.

```
// common.js
window.dataProm = fetch('/get-data').then(res => res.json());

dataProm
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  // .catch(handleErrors);
```

```
// homepage.js
dataProm
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  // .catch(handleErrors);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign the resulting promise to a globally scoped variable.

```js
// common.js
async function get_data() {
  const res = await fetch('/get-data');
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw res;
  }
  return res.json(); // return the data
}

// Assign to a variable
const dataPromise = get_data();

dataPromise.then(console.log);
```

```js
// homepage.js
dataPromise.then(console.log); // why does everyone log everything ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```

Answer (score 0):

Three (3) [node](/questions/tagged/node) [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) solutions that doesn't rely on `window`.

There are a few viable approaches here. One being a `global` variable, another being through `classes` and/or passing an instance of the function/class to the respective files.
But in general, what I think you're looking for is the `static` keyword in other languages. Well, it exists in JavaScript as well.

---

#### Static keyword

Benefits of this approach is that you don't have to create a new instance of the class and pass it around as a reference *(see last example for that)*.

Essentially, everywhere you want to get the *shared resource* value. Just import the `common` file and use the `getStaticProperty` method (in this example).

*common.js*

```
export default class Common {
  static staticProperty = 0;

  static getStaticProperty() {
    return this.staticProperty;
  }

  static setStaticProperty(val) {
    this.staticProperty = val;
  }
}
```

*a.js*

```
import Common from './common';

export default function a() {
  Common.setStaticProperty(321); // here we set the value
}
```

*b.js*

```
import Common from './common';

export default function b() {
  console.log(Common.getStaticProperty()); // prints 321
}
```

*index.js*

```
import a from './a';
import b from './b';
a();
b();
```

[Full demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-t6kpr6?file=index.js)

---

#### Global variable

*common.js*

```
let globalValue = 0;

function setSharedValue(val) {
  globalValue = val;
}

function getSharedValue() {
  console.log('global value', globalValue);
}

export { setSharedValue, getSharedValue };
```

*a.js*

```
import { getSharedValue, setSharedValue } from './common';

function runA() {
  setSharedValue(3); // here we set the value to '3'
  getSharedValue(); // prints 3
}

export default runA;
```

*b.js*

```
import { getSharedValue } from './common';

function runB() {
  console.log('from B');
  getSharedValue(); // also prints 3
}

export default runB;
```

*index.js*

```
import a from './a';
import b from './b';

a(); // 3 
b(); // from b, 3
```

[Full demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-2fffns?file=index.js)

---

#### Classes (and pass by reference)

*common.js*

```
export default class Common {
  constructor() { // redundant
    this.sharedValue = 0;
  }

  getSharedValue() {
    return this.sharedValue;
  }

  setSharedValue(value) {
    this.sharedValue = value;
  }
}
```

*a.js*

```
export default function A(commonInstance) {
  const sharedValue = commonInstance.getSharedValue();
  console.log('shared value', sharedValue);
}
```

*index.js*

```
import Common from './common';
import A from './a';

const shared = new Common();
shared.setSharedValue(55); // set the common value to 55.
A(shared); // prints 55
```

[Full demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-5mxonz?file=b.js)

---

In summary, you can apply these approaches to variables, functions and classes in order to get a shared variable across different javascript files.